# Computing new attribute for a list of multiple dataframes and unlists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I request your help in R to resolve the issue.
I have dataframes as given below

```
df1

a,b,c,d

1,2,3,4

1,2,3,4

1,2,3,4

df2

a,b,c,d

1,2,3,4

1,2,3,4

1,2,3,4

1,2,3,4
```

I need to perform an operation on each dataframe as given below

```
 df1$value <- 0.12*df1$a+0.24*df1$b+0.56*df1$c
```

As read from another Stack Overflow answer, it is advised to put in a list of all the dataframes. I was trying use the below statement to do so. It worked

```
df_list <- list(ls(pattern='df*'))
```

Now I am not able to compute the new attribute with below code using lapply

```
res <- lapply(dflist, function(x) {
          0.12*grep(x[[a]])+0.24*grep(x[[b]])+0.56*grep(x[[c]]))
          })
```

After performing the above operation I want to reform my dataframes without a list.

Comment: It is better to keep the dataframe in the list.  Why do you need the `grep(x[[a]])` (BTW, it is not correct also).  Shouldn't it be `0.12*x[[a]] + 0.24*x[[b]] + 0.56 * x[[c]]`

Comment: Forgot the quotes i.e. `x[['a']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `R`, it is better keep the data.frames in a `list`.  If we really need to update the data.frames objects in the global environment, use `list2env` after `transform`ing the 'df_list' with a 'value' column.

```
df_list <- mget(ls(pattern='df\\d+'))
res <- lapply(df_list, transform, value = 0.12*a + 0.24*b + 0.56*c)
list2env(res, envir = .GlobalEnv)
df1
#  a b c d value
#1 1 2 3 4  2.28
#2 1 2 3 4  2.28
#3 1 2 3 4  2.28
 df2
#  a b c d value
#1 1 2 3 4  2.28
#2 1 2 3 4  2.28
#3 1 2 3 4  2.28
#4 1 2 3 4  2.28
```

---

We get the values of the string (`ls(pattern='df\\d+'))`) in a `list` using `mget`, then loop through the `list` of `data.frame`s (`lapply(df_list, ...`), `transform` to create a new column 'value' in each of the `data.frame` and finally update the objects in the global environment with `list2env`.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L), b = c(2L, 2L, 2L), c = c(3L, 
3L, 3L), d = c(4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), b = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
c = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), d = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, Thanks alot for your reply. I am getting object a not found in script "res <- lapply(df_list, transform, value = 0.12*a + 0.24*b + 0.56*c)"

Comment: @NaveenSrikanth  I created two objects 'df1' and 'df2' (updated the 'data') and run the code.  It is working for me.

Comment: Akrun, Thanks alot . I have struggling with this from past three days. The prob now I had was I kept two NULL dataframes in a list, so it didn't work. I am really thankful to u . It worked

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with matrix multiplication:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", text=
"a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4")

df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", text=
"a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4")

df1$value <- as.matrix(df1) %*% c(0.12, 0.24, 0.56, 0)
df1
df2$value <- as.matrix(df2) %*% c(0.12, 0.24, 0.56, 0)
df2
```

or

```
df1$value <- as.matrix(df1[1:3]) %*% c( 0.12, 0.24, 0.56)
df2$value <- as.matrix(df2[1:3]) %*% c( 0.12, 0.24, 0.56)
```

For working with a list of dataframes you can do:

```
L <- list(df1, df2)
lapply(L, function(x) transform(x, value=as.matrix(x[1:3]) %*% c( 0.12, 0.24, 0.56)))
```